# Strange ActionBar bug in Android 4.3 when ActionBar is hidden programatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm experiencing this strange bug, when I call `getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();`. It's not happening on 4.2 or lower, it's just on the Android 4.3. It's strange and I can't figure out what's causing it. I've tried the hierarchy view with no luck. As you can see, on attached screenshots, there is a white stripe where the bottom part of split ActionBar used to be. Any ideas what this might be? I googled a lot and didn't get anything that'd help me with this issue.

[image: before .hide()]
[image: after .hide()]

EDIT:

This is the activity code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ececec" />
```

and this is the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ececec" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Načítání článku"
        android:textColor="@color/postDetail_textColor_default"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ececec"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What does your layout look like for this activity/fragment?

Comment: Please see the edit, I've added the layout code.